# Azure DevOps won't make description field read-only

Tags: azure

I added rules to make some fields of my backlog items read-only for everyone who hasn't got a specific role. That works for all fields except the description field. The description field remains editable. Why does my rule not work on the description field?
The screenshot below shows the configuration of the read-only rule.

[image: read-only rule on field description]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the rule and recreated it. That fixed the issue.